# How to name my options when switching a line between 'topleft to bottomright' and 'topright to bottomleft'

Tags: editor

So i have an editor that can draw lines, and in this editor the user needs to be able to choose between a line that draws from  'topleft to bottomright' OR 'topright to bottomleft'. So visually it would look like a '/' or '\'.

How would i name these two options? And what would be the best way to do this? A radio button? Or a button that switches value?

Comment: Are the absolute only options for a line? and what is the reason for drawing the line?

Comment: Yes, in this case, those are the only two options. The reason for drawing a line is for drawing a line. It's an editor that can draw lines, shapes, text, etc ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just call it 'Line' and use buttons with icon labels to distinguish between the types.**

This is what the Balsamiq mockup tool (built in to the UXSE Q&A UI) does.

[image]

(The label is 'Arrow' because the element is called "Arrow / Line".)

In their case, the icon is an arrow because that's what you get, but in yours could just be to show the direction of the line.

Additionally, you could use a tooltip on hover that stated the full name of the line type e.g. Top Left > Bot. Right etc.